# how to create or add new client with password without restarting mqtt eclipse mosquitto server through java code?

Tags: java, plugins, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

i have tried command line methods to create client but i want to create using java code via dynamic security plugin or any other method without restarting server

in this code i am getting issue that when the command is executed then it is not waiting for password to enter after command is executed how to solve this issue ?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mosquittoDir = "D:\\jar folder\\mosquitto";
        String username = "myadmin";
        String password = "root";
        String clientName = "sk123";

        try {
            // Set the working directory to the Mosquitto directory
            File mosquittoDirectory = new File(mosquittoDir);

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/k", "mosquitto_ctrl -u admin -P root dynsec createClient sk123");
            processBuilder.directory(mosquittoDirectory);
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Read the output from the command in a separate thread
           
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                        System.out.println(line);
                        if (line.contains("New password for " + username + ":")) {
                            // Provide the password
                            OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
                            outputStream.write((password).getBytes());
                            outputStream.flush();
                        } else if (line.contains("Reenter password for " + username + ":")) {
                            // Provide the password again for re-entering
                            System.out.println("Password re-enter called");
                            OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
                            outputStream.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
                            outputStream.flush();
                        } else if ((line.contains("This means all of the configuration changes you are making are visible on the network, including passwords."))) {
                            break;
                            
                        }
                    }
                   // process.destroy();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            // Wait for the process to complete
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
           
            // Wait for the output thread to complete
           

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The short answer is don't do it this way. Use one of the authentication plugins and add/remove users from a database. (Otherwise how to get the `password_file` to be re-read is detailed in the `mosquitto.conf` man page https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

Comment: Also don't try and use java to run the `mosquitto_ctrl` command. If you want to use the dynamic_sec plugin then you should just send the MQTT messages directly from the java app to the broker

Comment: actully my users are connecting to mqtt mosquitto server and i want to just add these user to mosquitto server for authentication and please can you explain me how to add user by sending messages from java actully i have read the doc you mentioned still i didnt get and thank you for your reply and help

Comment: Read this feature https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1779